# How do I add a tool to my project?

Tags: c#

I have made my own tool/Loading bar in my Solution called CustomPbar.
I have a Form application with this tool in the designer.
When I copy the program to another location it gives me an error,

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   raidzer0.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   519888ba
Problem Signature 04:   RaidZer0
Problem Signature 05:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   519888ba
Problem Signature 07:   1
Problem Signature 08:   6
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  3081
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I believe this is because the custom ProgressBar/Pbar is not attached to the form?
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you Copy your Tool? is that toolbar in a own DLL or included in you first Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly shown in your error:

```
Problem Signature 09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Which means it is not able to find the dll for your tool. What you need to do is:

Either create the same folder structure in your target machine, where the tool exist in your original machine, or move the tool to a common folder and reference it from there.

Answer (score 0):

investigate this link

[Windows Error Reporting and CLR integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx)

and these SO threads

[c#, problem running compiled app on other systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758317/c-problem-running-compiled-app-on-other-systems-scintillanet-signature-err)

[C# windows appication Event: CLR20r3 on application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244694/c-sharp-windows-appication-event-clr20r3-on-application-start)